# атрибут data-* в документе

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Есть такая конструкция:

```
page( $('.ajax').data('send') )
```

В свою очередь `.ajax`:

```
<a href="#" class="ajax" data-send="some2send">Something</a>
<a href="#" class="another" data-send="some">Something</a>
```

Так вот в чем проблема, при клике на `.ajax` оно передает значение `data` на функцию, которая обрабатывает этот запрос, это в идеале. НО! Оно почему-то хватает значение `data-` и с `.another`... Как от этого избавится? Чтобы только на том, что было кликнуто, а не все

добавляю `pages`:

```
function pages (url) {
    $('.ajax').live('click', function(){ 
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
          $('.middle_container').html(router(data));
        });
    });

    return false;
}
```

`data-send` имеют разные значения

Comment: Похоже, что проблема в функции-обработчике клика (который вы почему-то не считаете нужным приводить). `$(...).data` работает так как и должно.

Comment: Судя по вашему коду из вопроса у вас в data-send из .another аналогичные данные. Как вы определили, что ваш код берет значение именно из .another?

Comment: При нажатии на .ajax оно отправляет 2 запроса: 1. из этого класса, 2. из .another

Comment: А зачем вы вообще передаете значение `data-*` атрибута в функцию `pages`? Не проще ли получать это значение при клике?

Comment: Получается в дате лежит ссылка для запроса на апи, при клики оно как раз и срабатывает, я так думаю...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот посмотрите на этот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/x6sam8m4/2/

```js
var $result = $("#result");

function ajaxRequest (data) {
    $result.text(data);
}

$(".ajax, .another").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var data = $(this).data("send");
    ajaxRequest(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="ajax" data-send="some2send_1">Something</a>
<a href="#" class="another" data-send="some2send_2">Something</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: А зачем вы дублируете код один-в-один в обработчиках `click`?

Comment: Вообще конечно же не зачем. Чтобы автору было понятней. Поправил.